# Self join in rank query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, self-join

I want to perform self join on the following query:

```
select 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER) as Trip_Leg_Id
from  [dbo].[Src_Nol_Txns] s1
inner join
```

so that, I join the current record with the record of rank -1
how to achieve that?

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: i have no sql server 2012, but you could use the LAG Function [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as 
(  SELECT * ,
          LAG(CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER) AS PreviousSEQ   
     FROM table ); 
select cte1.*, cte2.* 
  from cte as cte1 
  join cte as cte2 
    on cte2.CARD_ID = cte1.CARD_ID 
   and cte2.BE_BUSINESS_DATE = cte1.BE_BUSINESS_DATE 
   and cte2.CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER = cte1.PreviousSEQ
   and cte1.PreviousSEQ <> cte1.CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER;
```

I think the last and will deal with duplicates

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it

```
With TripID AS
(
select 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER) as Trip_Leg_Id
from  [dbo].[Src_Nol_Txns] s1
)
select *
from TripID a
join TripID b
   on b.Trip_Leg_Id=a.Trip_Leg_Id - 1
  and a.CARD_ID=b.CARD_ID
  and a.BE_BUSINESS_DATE =b.BE_BUSINESS_DATE
```

Comment: I think that will join across CARD_ID and BE_BUSINESS_DATE and is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: Here, I changed the code so that CARD_ID and BE_BUSINESS_DATE are not joined together.

Comment: Are not?  Not would be <>

Answer (score 1):

since i could access sql fiddle, i can give an example how it could work with LAG without any selfjoin:

link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1296a/4/0

```
select *
     , SEQN_LAST = LAG(CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER, 1, NULL) 
       OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE 
         ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER) 
     , DUMMY_LAST = LAG(DUMMY, 1, NULL) 
       OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE 
         ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER) 
     , SEQN_NEXT = LAG(CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER, 1, NULL) 
       OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE 
         ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER DESC) 
     , DUMMY_NEXT = LAG(DUMMY, 1, NULL) 
       OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE 
         ORDER BY CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER DESC) 
from ( values 
      ('1','2012-01-01',1,'dummy1'),
      ('1','2012-01-01',2,'dummy2'),
      ('1','2012-01-01',3,'dummy3'),
      ('2','2012-01-01',1,'dummy1'),
      ('2','2012-01-01',2,'dummy2'),
      ('2','2012-01-01',3,'dummy3')) 
      Src_Nol_Txns(CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE, CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER, DUMMY)
order by CARD_ID, BE_BUSINESS_DATE, CARD_TXN_SEQ_NUMBER
```